# Как отследить открытие popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно при открытии одного popup скрыть другой. Имеется: попап с кнопками. При нажатии на кнопку в этом попап всплывает другой попап, но поверх открытого. Нужно закрыть предыдущий попап (с кнопками) когда открылся новый. Как с js этот момент обыграть?
При нажатии на ссылку всплывает попап с кнопками. Нажимаем на кнопку в этом попап и всплывает другой попап, а тот не закрывается. То есть получается новое окно открыто поверх старого. Нужно закрыть первое.

Comment: Попробуйте обыграть в коде

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Иногда удивляюсь что такие персонажи делают на сайте. Вы если не знаете, так не лезьте. Ерунду написал и думает классный ответ дал.

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку всплывает попап с кнопками. Нажимаем на кнопку в этом попап и всплывает другой попап, а тот не закрывается. То есть получается новое окно открыто поверх старого. Нужно закрыть первое.

Comment: Иногда удивляюсь что такие персонажи делают на сайте. Вы считаете что все знают ваш конкретный код и сразу напишут конкретное решение со всеми селекторами и вложенностью, которая у вас имеется? Ерундовое описание дал и думает все телепаты

Comment: Нужно закрыть - закрой.

Comment: С тобой алеша мы закончили.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

При нажатии на кнопку делайте не только открытие нового popup'а, но закрывайте первый.

Comment: Можно кусочек кода для примера? Ковыряю чужой код. Там не разберешься. Думал отдельный файл js подключить который будет закрывать окно.

Comment: Код зависит от разных факторов, например это плагин или нет, если плагин, то какой. Есть ли там крестик закрытия окна, какие там селекторы, а простое установление display none не сломает ли другую логику, а есть ли сзади бэкграунд и т.д. Так что нет, нельзя дать конкретный код на абстрактное окно

Comment: Там получается нужно проверить открылось ли новое окно и скрыть один класс. Если прописать display: none; то работает нормально. С js можно проверить открытие окна и исходя из этого присвоить классу none?

Comment: Зависит от того, что значит "открытие окна" и что именно оно (окно) из себя представляет. Может это плагин и оно открывается долго и асинхронно - тогда один способ, может оно подтягивается аяксом - другой способ, может это плагин со своими конкретными методами колбэками - третий способ, а может оно просто тупо невидимо - четвёртый способ

Comment: Код первого нашел, написан на jquery как я понял. А вот второе окно уже сделал через плагин popup maker. В нем поля не работаю для заполнения пока не убрать открытое первое окно.

Comment: .............. 

Comment: Закинул на тест http://ct41468-wordpress-25.tw1.ru/  Кнопка Обратная связь и там отправить на email